Book series about a person who gets trapped in Minecraft
I actually want to know the names of two books like this so I can find them and hopefully read them in the future, mainly for nostalgia reasons but yeah.

Book 1:
Lore-Wise, I believe that a malfunctioning modem somehow caused the protagonist to get sucked into his Minecraft world. Specific details in the plot include:

Him meeting his friend who is not trapped in the game with him but playing from his PC.
Him going to the village for some help. One of the villagers freaks out because the protagonist was responsible for their wife's death by making a skeleton shoot her. Eventually, the elder of the village convinces him to relax and he leads the protagonist to a secret base where he explains that hostile mobs are trying to escape into the real world, and only the protagonist could stop him by making it to a special "source" server. Somehow, the protagonist and the village elder do something which transports them to another Minecraft server closer to this "source." There was also a sequel, which I haven't read.


Book 2:
Lore-Wise, the way they get trapped was because a lightning strike caused all the protagonists to become trapped in Minecraft.
The server is apparently cursed to cause players participating in it to get trapped inside it. The protagonists are not the only ones who get sucked in.
Specific plot details:

I don't remember much, but I do remember a part where, before they got sucked into the game, there were griefers who were trying to destroy the protagonists' rollercoaster they worked hard on. After they get sucked in, we learn these griefers were doing this because they were frustrated that they were not trapped in the game with them. However, now that they were, everyone was one the same team. Apparently, there was only one person with the power to free them on the server, but he probably wouldn't do it.


Any ideas for either of these books?
Clarification: The two books I mentioned are parts of separate series. They are not related to each other nor written by the same authors.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Your title says this is a series, but you don't mention how they books relate.  Are they a "series" in the sense that they have the same publisher and topic, or do they actually share characters or other plot-related elements?

The two books I mentioned are parts of separate series. Within each book's respective series, the answer is yes to both those questions, but they are not related to each other. I only put these two books in the same post because they shared similar context and plot, which I thought was more likely to help identify one of them.

If they are two distinct books, please may you [edit] this question to ask about one book, and ask a new question for the second book. Even if they are related in that they're set in the Minecraft universe, if they are different books by different authors, they should be separate questions

Max Brook's Minecraft:The Island? The young protagonist arrives at a desert island only to realise they are in a game of Minecarft and they have to learn how the world works. There's also a sequel called Minecraft: The Mountain.

No. It's not this. It was an unofficial release.

@Catman321 Rats, good luck with finding that one then, once those are gone it's not easy to get back to them.
